# Boolean validation not passing but params is present Rails 4 and Devise

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm running a validation for Terms of Service with a boolean checkbox in rails 4 with devise, I see the params being passed but my validation still throws up an error.

html.erb

```
<%= check_box_tag(:agree) %>
<%= label_tag(:agree, "I Agree") %>
```

devise_permitted_parameters.rb

```
def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :first_name << :last_name << :agree
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :first_name << :last_name
end
```

It does not work if I do this in the model:

```
validates_acceptance_of :agree, :allow_nil => false, :accept => true, :on => :create
```

The server:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"VfMsm8nigtdMDh/jo6SyU8mUt5LIWlz0ymuiJwl4qFY=",
"user"=>{"first_name"=>"c", "last_name"=>"c", "email"=>"abc@def.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "agree"=>"1", "commit"=>"Register"}
Unpermitted parameters: first_name, last_name
```

Not sure why I have unpermitted params ... it only appears if I play around with the submission form.

It passes if I use this suggestion from other posts, but it also allows registration if the agree box is unchecked:

```
validates_inclusion_of :agree, :in => [true, false]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the code I realized that form_for was used so that's why the form_tag syntax didn't work as expected.  It also shows why it still output the submitted info.

I'm still not 100% sure why there were unpermitted parameters for first and last name.  I think it is a cookie issue from troubleshooting various things, if you restart the server it is fine again.

Hope this saves someone else time in the future.